# Onclick function in JavaScript not working. We need on click page to add active class and remove previous page

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

onclick function in JavaScript function is not working.  We need onclick page to add active class and remove previous active class.

All my pages come from database, they have not been manually added.  Pages are added only from admin panel.  We use 2 javascript code but they are not working the same way !!!!

```
    //javascript
  1.  $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#header-page li a").on("click", function() {
             $("#header-page li a").removeClass('active');
                $(this).toggleClass("active");
            });
        });



2.   // Header Pages Active
    $('#header-page li a').on('click', function () {
        $("#header-page li a").removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
    
    
    //code
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto  p-4 p-lg-0">
            <div class="header" id="header-page">
                
             <li> <a  class="active" href="index.php"></a> </li>
                    <?php
                            $id=$_GET['id'];
                            $qry="SELECT * FROM tbl_menu where visibility_status=0 order by position_order ASC ";                
                                $result=mysqli_query($connectiondb,$qry); 
                        
                                 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                                 {
                                    
                                ?>
                              
                                
                             <li><a class="mx-2 nav-item nav-link" href="<?php if($page_status=='true')?> <?php echo $row['page_link'];?>?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['page_name'];?></a></li>
                            
                             
                                
                            <?php } ?>  
                            
                                 </div>   
                    </div>  
            </div>
    
    
    ///css
    
    /*** Headers Active Pags***/
    #header-page  li {
        display: inline-block;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: var(--dark);
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: .5s;
        border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
        
    } 
    
    #header-page li:hover,
    #header-page li a.active {
        color: var(--primary);
        border-color: var(--primary);
    }
```

Comment: _Note:_ Your HTML is invalid. You can't have a `<li></li>` outside of `<ul>`, `<ol>` or `<menu>`. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li

Comment: till we added <ul> tag out side of <li> and active class working proper but after change page it was not showing that page ....it show only pervious page  ....like you have 3 page HOME/ABOUT/SERVICE    when you click 1st time home page not showing active but after click about page open about page  and page active in home page ...than if you click service page same process this time ABOUT page active ...So can solve please suggest

Comment: <li ><a class="mx-2 nav-item nav-link" href="<?php echo $row['page_link'];?>?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['page_name'];?></a></li>

Comment: we have only one <li><a> tag we received data from database

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something wrong the way you target the HTML elements, I'll suggest you to use classes for your anchors and all is good then:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>test2</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

    #header-page  li {
        display: inline-block;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: #444;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: .5s;
        border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;

    }

    #header-page li:hover,
    #header-page li a.active {
        color: #00ff00;
        border-color: #00ff00;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto  p-4 p-lg-0">
        <div class="header" id="header-page">

            <li> <a  class="active nav-link" href="#">index</a> </li>
            <li><a class="mx-2 nav-item nav-link" href="#">test 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="mx-2 nav-item nav-link" href="#">test 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="mx-2 nav-item nav-link" href="#">test 3</a></li>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".nav-link").on('click', function () {
            $(".nav-link").removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: we received data from database so we use only one <li><a> tag  if any idea about please suggest ....because in manual its working perfect but we need only dynamic basis ...                         <li ><a class="mx-2 nav-item nav-link" href="<?php echo $row['page_link'];?>?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['page_name'];?></a></li>

Comment: till page active working but after click different pages than active class show which you click pervious time